# Python Flask refresh through refresh icon in browser

Tags: python, flask

I have a very simple question and I have searched around here but no exact answers are available, if it is not possible , I would like a confirmation on the same.

I built a simple python flask web app. Everything is working fine, but I would like the web app page to refresh on clicking the refresh icon in the toolbar. I don't want auto refresh or a button /icon in the page.

Now, each time I have to execute the python code manually and then refresh the web page. Is it not possible to execute the python code merely by clicking the flask web page toolbar refresh icon?

It should not matter if there are any code / data changes to display. On clicking the web page toolbar refresh icon, the page should show old data if nothing has changed, and new data if things have changed by executing the associated python code on clicking the toolbar refresh icon.

Comment: "Now, each time I have to execute the python code manually and then refresh the web page" I don't understand what this means. What code are you executing manually?

Comment: I think you need to give more info here. You're talking about displaying results generated by code that is completely decoupled from the Flask app? There's multiple different options; you could in-line the code into the code that returns a response to the GET request, or have it spawn some subprocess (I don't see how that's viable tbh but we don't see what you're doing) or why not have the detached code working in its own continuous cycle and writing its latest results to some storage (database or otherwise) that's read and displayed on a page refresh?

Comment: I have a excel sheet having 20 rows, I am reading it in python doing some processing and displaying the result as a table in flak , when i click the refresh icon in http://127.0.0.1:5000/ the data should refresh say for example if i delete 2 rows from the excel and save it. But now I am having to execute the python code again through the IDE after making changes in the excel and saving it, get the same flask link as above AND then it shows the updated result. Once i make some edit in the excel sheet and save it and then click the refresh icon in an already open flask url,nothing happens

Comment: So the `@app.route` that returns a response to the browser should read the Excel file each time it is called. Refreshing the page sends a new GET request

Comment: @SukirtiSen As long as you are refreshing the `app.route` that is doing this excel reading and returns the table, then the data will refresh accordingly...

Comment: it does send a new GET request, I can see it in my IDE, but the flask uel doesnot get updated until i run the python code again from the IDE

Comment: @SukirtiSen What is this external python code that you're running? Can you please post examples.

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I'm not able to follow the description to see the issue.

Comment: @Harrison - Thanks, there was an issue with one of the files I was calling under app.route